# java.io.EOFException in HDFS 0.22.0

Tags: java, file-io, hadoop, hdfs

I am reading bytes from a file using:

```
FileSystem fs = config.getHDFS();
            try {

                Path path = new Path(dirName + '/' + fileName);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)fs.getFileStatus(path)
                        .getLen()];
                in = fs.open(path);

                in.read(bytes);
                result = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

There are about 15,000 files in the directory i am reading from. After a certain point I get this exception on the line in.read(bytes) :

```
2012-05-31 14:11:45,477 [INFO:main] (DFSInputStream.java:414) - Failed to connect to /165.36.80.28:50010, add to deadNodes and continue
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:298)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.DataTransferProtocol$Status.read(DataTransferProtocol.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReader.newBlockReader(BlockReader.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.getBlockReader(DFSInputStream.java:725)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:514)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:83)
```

Another Exception thrown is:

```
2012-05-31 15:09:14,849 [INFO:main] (DFSInputStream.java:414) - Failed to connect to /165.36.80.28:50010, add to deadNodes and continue
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.getBlockReader(DFSInputStream.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:514)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:83)
```

Please advice what could be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value from `in.read`, and assuming you can read the whole file in one go. Don't do that. Loop round until `read` returns -1 or you've read as much data as you want to. It's not clear to me whether you should really be trusting `getLen()` like this - what happens if the file grows (or shrinks) between the two calls?

I would suggest creating a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write to and a smallish (16K?) buffer as temporary storage, then looping round - read into the buffer, write that many bytes into your output stream, lather, rinse, repeat until `read` returns -1 to indicate the end of the stream. Then you can get the data out of your `ByteArrayOutputStream` and put it into the `ByteArrayInputStream` as before.

EDIT: Quick code, untested - there's similar (better) code in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), btw.

```
public static byte[] readFully(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Then just use:

```
in = fs.open(path);
byte[] data = readFully(in);
result = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

Also note that you should close your stream in a `finally` block, not just on exception. I'd also advise against catching `Exception` itself.

Comment: just to be clear, like this:
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
in = fs.open(path);
while(in.read(bytes)>0){
   baos.write(bytes);
}
result = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

I still get the error afte this change

Comment: @matroyd: Which bit do you not understand - what's wrong, or how to fix it? I've added some sample code, but the code in your comment *still* assumes that `in.read(bytes)` reads useful data into the *whole* of `bytes` on each iteration.